# .val(value) jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying jquery .val(vaue) function to set value of an attribute using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".qty-btn").click(function(){    

            var $qtyBox = $(".qty-btn").parent().find(".qty-box");
            var $qtyBoxQty = $qtyBox.text();
            var newVal = $qtyBoxQty;
            var form = $(".qty-btn").closest("form");

            if($qtyBoxQty > 0){
                newVal = eval(parseInt($qtyBoxQty) - 1);
                $qtyBox.text(newVal);
            }

            alert( newVal );

            $(".qty-btn").parent().find(".quantity").val(newVal);
            alert( "value = " + $(".qty-btn").parent().find(".quantity").val() );
        });                     


        $("button").click(function(){
            $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>  
<table class="table table-shopping-cart">
    <form action="" method="post" >
        <div class="control-group quantity">
             <div class="controls">
                 <a href="#" class="qty-btn qty-btn-minus">-</a>
                 <div class="qty-box">7</div>
                 <a href="#" class='qty-btn qty-btn-plus blur'>+</a>
                 <span style="display:none;" class="maxQty">1</span>
                 <select name="quantity" style="width: 60px" class="quantity" scliid="261021" id="quantity" >
                     <option value="3" selected="selected" >4</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this code is not producing the desired result as the code line:

```
$(".qty-btn").parent().find(".quantity").val(newVal);
```

is not working. whereas following works:

```
 alert( "value = " + $(".qty-btn").parent().find(".quantity").val() );
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Clarify please, what results do you have and what result you expect.

Comment: the value which you want to select is not present in <options> of select menu.Add it in your options.You can set only one value "3" to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `.quantity` is a `select` and when you set value for select it means that an `option` with that value must be present in `select` but here you have only one option in select and its `value is 3` and when you set value of select to `newVal` it is not in select.

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity" style="width: 60px" class="quantity" scliid="261021" id="quantity" >
                 <option value="3" selected="selected" >4</option>
                 <option value="4" selected="selected" >5</option>
</select>
```

This will select the option with value 4

```
$("#quantity").val("4");
```

And this will not do anything

```
$("#quantity").val("10");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.quantity option:selected").val();
```

To make sure you get the SELECTED quantity.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/0qbfspfp/

I reduced your code to this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <a href="#" class="qty-btn-minus">-</a>
    <a href="#" class='qty-btn-plus'>+</a>
    <select id="quantity" style="width:60px" qt="0"></select>
</div>
```

and did the plus and minus functions... I'm not sure if it will help, but I hope yes